# Can I have a sidecapped wrapfigure with text in bottom left corner of figure?

Tags: minipage, wrapfigure, sidecap

I have a figure i'd like to have wrapped text around it, while having a bottom-left sidecaption, is this possible?

Right now it looks like this:
[image]

but, I'd like it to look like this (made in paint):
[image]

The code for the first example image looks like this:

```
\begin{document}
\usepackage{graphicx,caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{wrapfig} %im not sure which of these are necessary

\newpage
\textit{RANDOM HEADER}

\begin{wrapfigure}[14]{r}{0.5\linewidth}
    \begin{minipage}{2cm}
        \centering
        \caption{This is a caption, with exactly this specific number of lines in it. The caption has to be in the lower left corner of the figure}
        \label{fig:stoejfralandevej}
    \end{minipage}
%
    \begin{minipage}{1\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{Lister/Figurer/000000.jpg}
    \end{minipage}
\end{wrapfigure}

RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT 
RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT 
RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT 
RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT 
RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM

\vspace{5cm}
\subsection{RANDOM HEADER}
RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT                         
RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM     
TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT     
RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM 
TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT 
RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM 
TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT 
RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM 
TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT 
RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT 
RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM 
TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT 
RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM 
TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT

\end{document}
```

Can anyone help me make it so it looks like example image 2?

Thank you :)

Comment: In your case, you aren't actually wrapping the text around the figure, you are just placing them side by side.  Use minipages and \captionof{figure}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know or measure the height of your image, you can put the caption in the same `minipage` with the text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,caption}

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{minipage}[t][10cm][s]{\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth-\columnsep}
\textit{RANDOM HEADER}

RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT 
RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT 
RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT 
RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT 
RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM
\vfill
\abovecaptionskip=0pt
  \captionof{figure}{This is a caption, with exactly this specific number of lines in it. The caption has to be in the lower left corner of the figure}
  \label{fig:stoejfralandevej}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\raisebox{\dimexpr \ht\strutbox - \height}{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth, height=10cm]{example-image}}


\vspace{5cm}
\subsection{RANDOM HEADER}
RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT                         
RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM     
TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT     
RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM 
TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT 
RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM 
TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT 
RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM 
TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT 
RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT 
RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM 
TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT 
RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM 
TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

---

This places the hyperref anchor at the top of the figure.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{hypcap}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setcaptype}[1]% #1 = figure or table
  {\def\@captype{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{minipage}[t][10cm][s]{\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth-\columnsep}
\setcaptype{figure}%
\hspace{\textwidth}\capstart\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\textit{RANDOM HEADER}

RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT 
RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT 
RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT 
RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT 
RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM
\vfill
\abovecaptionskip=0pt
\caption{This is a caption, with exactly this specific number of lines in it. The caption has to be in the lower left corner of the figure}
\label{fig:stoejfralandevej}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\raisebox{\dimexpr \ht\strutbox - \height}{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth, height=10cm]{example-image}}

\ref{fig:stoejfralandevej}
\vspace{5cm}
\subsection{RANDOM HEADER}
RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT                         
RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM     
TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT     
RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM 
TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT 
RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM 
TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT 
RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM 
TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT 
RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT 
RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM 
TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT 
RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM 
TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT RANDOM TEXT

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works for me.
Only one more thing, I get an error message now, "Package caption Warning: The option `hypcap=true' will be ignored ", how do I solve that? (is it even vital?)

Comment: To get the Warning (not an Error) you must also load hyperref. This is about placing the hyperref anchor at the top of the figure. Otherwise a `\ref` will link to the top of the caption.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm rather new to LaTeX, can you kindly explain what you mean, when you write "also *load* hyperref" ? I have a \usepackage{hyperref} in my preamble, is that it?
Thanks

Comment: Yes.  I added an example to my answer.